# How do I deny access by source IP when behind Amazon ELB or other proxy

Tags: nginx

Nginx has a nice feature that enables you to restrict access to resources by source IP address.

However, I've noticed that may not work in situation where nginx is behind a proxy or load balancer.  In my case the Amazon ELB.

I want to provide a status page for datadog agent and the Amazon ELB health checks.  So I want to allow local connections and those from the ELB but deny everything else.

The following does not work as expected as it allows traffic originating outside the ELB to access the status page as well.  The reason being because the IP will appear to originate from the ELB and the allow rules don't look at the headers to determine the real source of the request.  Is there a way to tell nginx what source IP to use to determine allow/deny rules?

```
location /status {
    stub_status;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow 10.0.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Just use the nginx real ip module.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that looks promising.  But not well documented.  Can you perhaps answer my question with a valid example config for Amazon ELB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Michael Hampton.  I can use the Real IP Module.
I wasn't aware of it.

The following worked.

```
http { 
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this configuration means anyone who can connect to your server directly (bypassing the load balancers) can fake any IP they like.

Comment: In my case I didn't allow direct connection.  But if you allow that then you can set the option set_real_ip_from and the ip range of the load balancer from memory.